# How to set permissions with .htaccess in a subfolder?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, server, root

I have a server with four websites, each with their own permissions .htaccess.
In one of the sites I created a folder with a project that connects php app / Database / WebSite.
Everything works if I use localhost as the server without .htaccess file, but if you use as ROOT subdirectory not working Register / Login to redirect index.html wrong.

Ex:

```
   `www.site1.com/
    www.site2.com/
    www.site3.com/
    www.site4.com/FolderWithSite/MyAppFolder/`
```

I tried to delete the .htaccess file but nothing! I tried to create a new .htaccess file in the subdirectory but nothing!
I think that somehow you can give permission to the subdirectory via .htaccess.
Any suggestions ??

Comment: Can you check the error log for the server?

Comment: yeah sure! but there are no errors

Comment: Can you increase the verbosity of the error log changing the `LogLevel` directive? See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#loglevel

Comment: Hi! I also tried to enable the error log on the server but does not report any error because instead of getting the right answer, they get another, that the redirect to the index.htm!
I spoke on the phone with tech support asking to remove the redirect absolute through instruments accessible only from them but do not know what to do!